# Modify a string in a column R from the front?

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify all the string in a column using apply. I need to add to the string from the beginning of the string, I've only been able to add at the end:

Example with a 1-row data frame (real data contains multiple rows)

```
a<-data.frame(num="WORLD",anything=23)

a$num <- a %>%
  select(num)%>%
     apply(1, paste0, "hello")

#Output data frame where num=="WORLDhello" I want it to be "helloWORLD"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can directly use `paste` as it is vectorized

```
library(dplyr)
a <-  a %>% 
        mutate(num = str_c('hello', num))
```

---

In `base R`, it would be

```
a$num <- paste0("hello", a$num)
```